# Compare Just Date Part of 2 DateTime Variables in LINQ with EF

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

Problem:
I have a search form that allows users to search for something where the record date falls between 2 dates (mm/dd/yyyy)

All of the records and objects are of type Datetime but all I need to compare is the date parts not the time part.

According to MSDN, the Date property is supported in LINQ however this statement as written will not allow me to append .Date to the lambda part:

**Error:**

```
The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.
```

**Example:**

```
x.DateCreated.Date
```

I am sure this problem comes up a lot - How do I solve it?

I guess I could pad the other date by appending 23:59:59 = 86399 secs to the <= part

Here is the statement. (db is a context object)

```
 model.Contacts = 
                db.Prospects.Where(x => x.DateCreated >= df.Date && x.DateCreated <= dt.Date)
                    .OrderByDescending(x => x.DateCreated)
                    .Take(100)
                    .ToList();
```

Comment: Which error message do you get when you try `x.DateCreated.Date`?

Comment: And what type is `DateCreated`?

Comment: DateCreated is just a DateTime type

Comment: I updated the question so it now includes the error message

Answer (score 14):

You should use the `TruncateTime` function:

```
EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(x.DateCreated)
```

Comment: replaced with `DbFunctions.TruncateTime`

Answer (score 4):

You should use **DbFunctions.TruncateTime**() in the Entity Framework version 6.

```
var fromDate = criteria.FromCreatedDate.Value.Date;
items.Where(i => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(i.CreatedOnDate) >=fromDate);
```

To get all items whose date is greater than *fromdate* ignoring the *timepart*.

Thanks @gor.

Answer (score 1):

I use the following solution

```
DateTime startDate = new DateTime(df.Year, df.Month, df.Day, 0,0,0);
DateTime endDate = new DateTime(df.Year, df.Month, df.Day, 23,59,59);

model.Contacts = 
                db.Prospects.Where(x => x.DateCreated >= startDate  && x.DateCreated <= endDate )
                    .OrderByDescending(x => x.DateCreated)
                    .Take(100)
                    .ToList();
```